# Swiftui 2.0 how can I access values in an api array and manipulate them

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I am new to swift and swift . I have an api call that returns an array, right now I am getting the data and displaying it in a list . What I would like to do is access the individual fields in the array and change them before it shows on the list  . This is my code . In the class **MainViewModel** I get the results from the API and I want to access the **fullname** string there so I can make it all uppercase . Any help would be great

```
struct MainModel: Decodable,Identifiable {
    var id: Int?
    var fullname: String?
    var time: String?
}

class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    func MainViewRequest(completion: @escaping([MainModel]) -> ())
    {
        let parameter = "id=1"
        
        let request = RequestObject(AddToken: true, Url: "Home/MainView", Parameter: parameter)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let Data = data else { return }
            do {
                let value = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<MainModel>.self, from: Data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // how can I get FullName property here
                    completion(value)
                }

            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}


struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var mainVM = MainViewModel()
   @State var model: [MainModel] = []
    var body: some View {
    
        List {
            ForEach(model) { value in
                Text("\(value.fullname ??  "")")
                Spacer()
                Text("\(value.time ??  "")")
            }
        }.onAppear(){
         mainVM.MainViewRequest() { data in
             model = data
         }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of ways you can achieve what you are trying to do.

**Use `map` to transform the values**

Any time you want to transform a collection of values `map` is worth considering.
The closure you supply is called on each element of the collection and you can return a transformed value (it can even be a different type). To keep things simple I will pack things back into one of your MainModel objects.

This is what this would look like:

```swift
let values = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<MainModel>.self, from: Data)
// Process the values off the main thread
let modifiedValues = values.map { value in
    MainModel(id: value.id,
              fullname: value.fullname?.uppercased(),
              time: value.time
    )}
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Use the processed values in the main thread
    completion(modifiedValues)
}
```

But this may not be the ideal way of doing things. The reason I say this is because converting something to uppercase is not a reversible operation so,
after going to all the trouble of downloading the data, you are throwing away
information.

**Transform in View**

If you just want to uppercase it for presentation purposes, you might be better
off doing it in your view:

```swift
ForEach(model) { value in
    Text("\(value.fullname?.uppercased() ??  "")")
    Spacer()
    Text("\(value.time ??  "")")
}
```

**Computed property in an extension**

This option is one I use a lot in my own code. In an extension I add computed display and format related computed properties.

```swift
extension MainModel {
    var displayFullName: String { fullname?.uppercased() ?? "" }
}
```

You then modify the loop of your view code as follows:

```swift
ForEach(model) { value in
    Text("\(value.displayFullName)")
    Spacer()
    Text("\(value.time ??  "")")
}
```

I like this approach because the original cased version is still available, you have not lost any information. You can use the extension throughout your code anywhere you need it... and it tidies up the view code.